# Unable to find the alert of application insights in portal

Tags: azure

Actually when i am seeing documnetation they haev given with different screens but when i ma going to azure portal it seemslike a different one

i am not understanding

what is happening there

pllease suggest me

refer documentation link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-alert

Please find the below screen shots

From Documentation:[image]

From Portal:[image]

please suggest me
Any help is appreciated

please find the belwo screen shots
ScreenShot-1[image]

ScreenShot-2
[image]

ScreenShot-3
[image]

ScreenShot-4
[image]

But after following this alsoi found one issue
It seems taking a lot of time even it is not giving any respons in portal UI.

ANy help is appreciated

Comment: They are moving to a new way of creating alert, more flexible. But the idea is still the same, you can still use that page to create a new alert so I suggest you just try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: send alert to multi users:**

[image]

The comment's from @Peter Bons is correct, the way to create alert has already been changed.

The doc you provided is written at `09/20/2017`, which is for the old alert named `classic alert`(and it will be retired soon). More about classic alert is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-classic.overview).

But if you can also use it(it's named classic alert), by clicking `View classis alerts` -> `Add metric alert`, then you can follow the doc to create alerts.

[image]

[image]

I suggest you'd better use the new alert, and you can do something more than the classic alert. Just click the  `New alert rule`, and it's easy to configure.

[image]

Comment: Yes i have found New alert rule But while creating a rule it is not creating rule every time it seems loading .

Comment: @NarsingRao, what do you mean "while creating a rule it is not creating rule every time it seems loading ."?  can you attach a screenshot? if you mean some items are in populating status, just wait for a while.

Comment: Please find above screen shots

Comment: @NarsingRao, the "condition" is mandatory. Without the condition, how does application insights know in which condition(like high cpu, exception occurs) it can send an alert?

Comment: But can we give multiple emails ?

Comment: @NarsingRao, yes, when create action group, check the checkbox "Email Azure Resource Manager Role". Note that it's based on the role, the users who are in the role can receive the alert email. I attached a screenshot in my answer.

Comment: @NarsingRao, if you have more issues, please let me know. And if the answer works for you, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks :).